# << overload operator, why it can't return to just class type(without reference)

Tags: c++

so this is a classic cout overloading friend member function. I have a simple question here. why it has to be return to the reference(ostream&)?. Why can't it be return to just ostream?

```
class Time { 
private:
   int hours;
   int minutes; 
public: friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Time& t) { os<<t.hours<< "hours, " <<t.minutes<< "minutes; 
return os; //why it can't return to just ostream(witout reference &)
}
```

Comment: Your sample code isn't valid (typoes). It should return the std::ostream by reference, not your custom type.

Comment: oh my bad i will edit it

Comment: I don't understand, what you are trying to accomplish. You could be using just the ostream stuff. Remember, you should be able to use the overloaded operator multiple times, like ```z = a << b << c;```. Can you give us an example of your class usage?

Comment: please do not change the question substantially after you received answers. One of the answers is refering to a question that is now not there anymore. Usually I revert such edits, but as your question clearly was not about returning a `Time`, I guess it is ok-ish. At least you should inform the answerer, I already did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ostream` objects are not copyable. Since they represent 'real world` resources, (consoles and files etc) it doesn't make any sense to copy them.

So because they are not copyable they have to be passed around by reference, so the correct return type from `operator<<` is a reference, `ostream&`.

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Time& t) {
    os << t.hours << "hours, " << t.minutes << "minutes; 
    return os;
}
```

That must be a reference because you can't copy an `ostream` object. What would this mean, copying the underlying file? No, no copy.

Comment: question has been edited. Perhaps remove the "It must retun an `ostream` object..." then the answer is in sync again